# How to apply Physics to GameObject containing multiple sprites

Tags: sprite, rotatetransform, gameobject

I'm new to Unity and my question may sound stupid, but please tolerate. I have added four sprites (small tiles) of different colors added to an empty GameObject so that they could be moved and rotated as a group. However, I'm unable to rotate the GameObject on its axis. My code is this:

```
void Update () {
    transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (90, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Please identify what I'm doing wrong here. Also, please give me an idea of how to detect which colored sprite was hit by the ball. If I attach separate colliders and rigidbodies to each of the colored sprites then they start behaving individually rather than as a group.

Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck asking on the dedicated Unity3D equivalent of SO -> http://answers.unity3d.com/